# How to stop SSH from falling back to password?

Tags: ssh, password, keys

A script regularly initiates an SSH connection from one server to another, using SSH keys.

However, once, the keys were briefly overwritten. This caused the SSH client to fall back to asking for a password, which had undesired knock-on effects.

Is it possible to instruct SSH to exit if key-based auth fails, and *not* fall back to asking for a password?

Thanks!

Wodow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to globally disable password authentication on your server you can use the `-o "PasswordAuthentication no"` option on the ssh command line e.g.

```
ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication no" YourHost
```

Answer (score 11):

You can stop password authentication by configuring the ssh daemon. Edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Uncomment and change the above line to `"no"`.

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Don't forget to restart your ssh daemon!

Answer (score 0):

vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

`# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!`

`#PasswordAuthentication yes`

`#PermitEmptyPasswords no`

`PasswordAuthentication yes`

change `yes` to `no`

:)